# Allow only number, decimal value upto two place, delete and backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

In my jquery code, I'm doing validation for only numbers and decimal point, it restricts special characters. But it also restrict backspace and delete key. So, if anyone can help me in this issue ?

Allow = [only numbers , decimal value upto two place, backspace and delete]

Restrict = [special character paste option and alphabets]

Validation to be done in jquery.

Thanks in advance.

```
   <label for="proposal_price">price</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proposal_price" name="proposal_price"> 

   $('#proposal_price').keypress(function(event) {
          var self = $(this);
          self.val(self.val().replace(/[^0-9\._\b]/g, ''));
          if (((event.which != 46 || (event.which == 46 && $(this).val() == '')) ||
          $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
               }
   }).on('paste', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
   });
```

Comment: `<input type="number" name="proposal_price" step="0.01" />` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i am working with jquery so wanted the solution in jquery. As this step= "0.01" can be removed from inspect element

Comment: Why is there a php tag here?

Comment: Anything client-side can be removed via browser tools.  Use Andreas' html advice, then rely fully on server-side validations.  If there is no php in your question, then there should be no php tag.

Comment: Because i am working with php files. So for that .

Comment: Why do you have a wordboundary inside your character class? Also, the dot doesn't need to be escaped in a character class.  I recommend a `+` quantifier after your character class so that consecutive matches can be replaced in one action.

Comment: seems its working fine https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/Lbvp7rkf/4/

Comment: @freedomn-m i understand. From i will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Vel in mozila its not working as expected

Comment: I cannot see any issue in mozila

Comment: It works fine for you? @Vel

Comment: Yes. Its working fine for me. My mozila version is 67.0b11

Comment: I see but for me its not allowing me to use bakspace and delete. My version is 60.0.1

Comment: update the mozila and check

Comment: You can use http://www.bestjquery.com/?l_FGl9aS

Comment: It worked i was using keypress as soon as I use keyup everything worked for me. @vel